# Opencart set a special by percentage of product price

Tags: php, opencart

I have been looking all over the internet for an extension or code that allows me to place a percentage off.  I would like to insert a percentage value in place of the price value and have it calculate the price rounded to the nearest cent.  I am looking for some direction.

Before all the comments come... I cant use static price specials because our product prices are updated through an api by quickbooks and the api can not be modified to update the specials.

Opencart V3.

Comment: How about you tell us what you found so far or what code you tried? For example, just a quick google search already yielded a result off the marketplace:  https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=21450 So how about you take what's there and see how close you can convert it for 3.0 use or custom use. I don't see it being that difficult to convert that extension to 3.0 use considering not too much has changed for specials from 2.2 to 3.0

Comment: So you want me to purchase an outdated plugin that does not do anywhere near what I am looking to accomplish to attempt to figure out what I am trying to do.  The plugin you showed me simply gives you the ability to insert a percent that then generates the $ amount on mouseup.  If there was a plugin out there I would have found it.